# Must declare the scalar variable "@0" error come during INSERT query in SSMS V18.10

Tags: sql-server, sequelize-cli

I am getting this error while executing INSERT query which is generated from sequelize.

```
INSERT INTO [table_name] ([fname], [lname], [userid], [createdAt],[updatedAt], [version])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[id], INSERTED.[fname], INSERTED.[lname], INSERTED.[userid], INSERTED.[createdAt], INSERTED.[updatedAt], INSERTED.[version] 
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, @4, @5, @6);
{"0":"1","1":"revti","2":"paggi","3":"4","4":2022-04-23 11:14:06.781 +00:00","5":"2022-04-23 11:14:06.781 +00:00","6":0}
```

I am new to SSMS, can you please help?

Comment: You cannot simply copy/paste code that is parameterized in some other language into a SSMS query window and expect it to compile and execute correctly. You will need to change that code into pure TSql - and there are many problems to overcome to do that.

Comment: To execute the parameterized query in SSMS. you'll need to declare @0...@6 as variables and assign values before the INSERT statement or use `sp_executesql` with the parameter definitions and values specified. However, the insert statement has 6 column names specified and 7 values, which will result in an error. Guessing `@0`  should be omitted from the values clause as it looks to be intended as an output parameter for a generated `IDENTITY` value.

Comment: If the insert statement is the actual one generated by sequelize, it seems there is is an error in the code.